# How to decrement an attribute value after insert on another table? pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have book table book

```
CREATE TABLE Book (
     ProductNo   CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
     ISBN  char(13) ,
      No_OfCopies  int DEFAULT 1,
);
```

and Circulation table

```
CREATE TABLE Circulation (
BorrowNo    CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
MemberID    CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
ProductNo         CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
IssueNo               CHAR(5) ,
StartDate   date NOT NULL,
EndDate date NOT NULL,
Fine         money
);
```

I try to create trigger to reduce the No_OfCopies in book table for each inserting in Circulation table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION book_borrow()
returns trigger
as 
$reduce_copies$
begin

    update book set no_ofcopies = no_ofcopies - 1
     where Productno = new.Productno ;
    RETURN NEW;
end;
$reduce_copies$ language plpgsql;
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER book_reduce_copies
    AFTER INSERT
    ON circulation
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION book_borrow();
```

but it's doesn't work!

Comment: From PSQL your solution work perfectly fine, Its seems problem would be auto-commit turned off from pgadmin.

postgres=# select * from Book;
 productno |     isbn      | no_ofcopies 
-----------+---------------+-------------
 PG10      | ISBN_PG10     |           10
(1 row)
postgres=# INSERT INTO Circulation VALUES('1', '1', 'PG10', '', current_timestamp, current_timestamp, 1);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from Book;
 productno |     isbn      | no_ofcopies 
-----------+---------------+-------------
 PG10      | ISBN_PG10     |           9
(1 row)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: [Don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Answer (score 2):

Although this doesn't answer the question directly, I believe it's the best outcome.

Keeping totals like this up to date is an example of *denormalised* data and requires triggers, which are less obvious to debug and hard to get right in larger scaled situations.

Instead of using database Kung Fu, store only the total stock in Book and use a view to show the calculated value.

```
CREATE TABLE Book (
    ProductNo CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    ISBN char(13) ,
    Stock int DEFAULT 1,
);

CREATE VIEW Book_Copies as
SELECT b.ProductNo, b.ISBN, Stock, Stock - count(*) AS No_OfCopies
FROM Book b
JOIN circulation c ON c.Productno = b.Productno
GROUP BY b.ProductNo, b.ISBN, Stock;
```

The advantage is that the calculated value is always correct; changes outside the trigger's control, such as deleting rows from circulation, are not catered for when storing the calculated column.

It's also easier to code and understand, both of which are very important.